# How do I center align my view in a custom Layout?

Tags: android, layout

I'm making use of a custom layout with a custom view. The layout is a `RelativeLayout` and the view is an `ImageView`.
The `ImageView` is scaled based on the smallest width or height of the screen, to keep the ratio of the image I want to display while still showing the entire image.

What I can't figure out is how to center align the ImageView in the layout.

It's a very basic layout:

```
public class ImageViewLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public final CustomImageView mCustomImageView;

    public ImageViewLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mCustomImageView = new CustomImageView(context);
        this.addView(mCustomImageView);
    }
}
```

And the ImageView is (very large but I'll try and keep it down for readability and extend if wanted):

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
      public CustomImageView(Context context) {
          super(context);
          mContext = context;
          init();
      }

  public init() {
      setBackgroundColor(0xFF222222);
      LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
      setLayoutParams(params);
      calculateAndDisplayBitmap();
  }
```

}

I calculate the size of the image I want to display after the initial layout and the image is always placed top left, no matter what kind of tricks I try to do with the layout.
The background is stretched to fill the entire screen (`FILL_PARENT` in the parameters suggest that it should) but no matter what I do to the layout I can't get the bitmap to center.

I'm really opting for a layout-based positioning of the bitmap instead of a calculated-pixel-based one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in ImageViewLayout.java

```
mCustomImageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to work out. When trying to do this I get; "The method setGravity(int) is undefined for the type CustomImageView"
This to me, means that the CustomImageView doesn't have a method called setGravity. Should I implement this method in the CustomImageView and in that case, what should I put in it?